# AREA macro in ARM assembly

Tags: assembly, arm

I have started ARM assembly programming, the program begins with

```
AREA PROGRAM,CODE,READONLY
    ENTRY
```

I was wondering if there is another macro which can be used in place of `READONLY`, allowing changes in this memory section by program instruction.

I know it is always advised to keep program memory as it would prevent from code corruption by other instructions but I want to know just for the sake of knowledge.

Comment: This [is documented](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.kui0100a/armasm_cacbjgcc.htm) at the ARM infocenter site.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just leave out the `READONLY` keyword, because `READONLY` is the default for `CODE` areas. Try this:

```
AREA PROGRAM,CODE,READWRITE
    ENTRY
```

But then you have to make sure that all `PROGRAM` areas in your program are declared identically, because the linker uses the first `AREA` directive for a given section, and ignores the rest. So perhaps this is better:

```
AREA MYPROGRAM,CODE,READWRITE
    ENTRY
```